# Can flute produce coherent radiation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, acoustics, laser, spectroscopy

A flute is a wind instrument in which the interaction between a player supplying a modulated jet stream and the column of air in the cylinder result in the formation of longitudinal sound waves.

The sound spectrum of the flute comprises the fundamental wavelength and harmonics which are integer multiples of the fundamental. These are well-known features - Pipes and Harmonics (unsw.edu.au).

The oscillation of air molecules in the flute can be represented by a superposition of normal modes forming stationary and traveling waves. The boundary conditions of the flute (both ends open to the atmosphere) impose quantisation conditions.

> Those emerging collective excitations in the periodic elastic arrangement of molecules become phonons- quantized sound waves.  - Wikipedia

The flute is filled with an exhaled air of the player. This gas is mainly a mixture of nitrogen $\sim 79 \%$, oxygen $\sim 18 \%$, and carbon dioxide whose concentration may reach $2.5 \%$. On the molecular level, the energy provided by the player is distributed between multiple DOF: translational, electronic, vibrational, and rotational. All those energies are quantized.
Even at room at temperature ($298 ~\text K$) there would be $\sim 13~\text{ppm}$ of $\text N_{2}$ molecules in an excited vibrational state $v = 1$ (Boltzmann distribution).

Excited vibrational states $\text N_{2} \left\{ v_{1} \left( 1 \right) \right\}$ molecules cannot lose their energy through radiation because they have no permanent electric dipole moment therefore, they are metastable and relatively long-lived. The additional energy supplied by a sound wave is causing a further population inversion. The vibrational frequency of $\text{CO}_{2}$ associated with asymmetric stretch is $2349 ~ \text{cm}^{-1}$ and bending with $667 ~\text{cm}^{-1}$ is IR active and can be observed by the Rovibrational spectroscopy.

$\text N_{2} \left\{ v_{1} \left( 1 \right) \right\}$ and $\text{CO}_{2} \left\{ v_{3} \left( 1 \right) \right\}$ being nearly perfectly resonant (total molecular differential is within $3 ~ \text{cm}^{-1}$,… collisionally de-excites vibrational mode by transferring mode energy to the $\text{CO}_{2}$ molecule, causing the carbon dioxide to excite to its asymmetric stretch $\left\{ v_{3} \left( 1 \right) \right\}$ vibrational mode quantum state. The $\text{CO}_{2}$ then radiatively emits at either $10.6 ~ \mu\text m$ by dropping to the $\left\{ v_{1} \left( 1 \right) \right\}$ (symmetric stretch) vibrational mode, or $9.6 ~ \mu\text m$ by dropping to the $\left\{ v_{20} \left( 2 \right) \right\}$ (bending) vibrational mode.” - Wikipedia.

The stimulated radiation would be triggered by the thermal radiation of the gas. The peak wavelength of the exhaled air at $38^\circ\text C$ is $\sim 9.3$ microns and the energy is $\sim -0.1 ~ e\text V$.  - Hyperphysics

This is the resonance level of $\text{CO}_{2}$ radiation.
Shouldn’t we then observe some coherent radiation emerging from the flute?

Comment: Absolutely, a flute can produce optical radiation. All you have to do is to blow hard enough. You wouldn't have to use CO2 for that, though. Any gas will do, as long as you blow hard enough. Will it be "coherent"? Some of it will be, if you manage to excite a molecular or atomic transition.

Comment: Thanks, for the positive comments. Although I think that the presence of CO2 is essential because it reduces the energy required to excite the molecules to the asymmetric stretch. I'm speculating that radiation may take place even without the flute i.e. when we sing  ?

Comment: Nothing stops you from putting a far IR spectrometer down your throat. Good luck with your experiments!

Comment: Great, I will try that, but also do you think that the coherent radiation could act as a waveguide helping to propagate the acoustic soundwave, similar to Bohmian pilot wave theory ?

Comment: That, too, can only be answered experimentally. I am looking forward to the outcomes of yours.

Comment: What test did you have in mind to verify pilot wave theory ?

Comment: I would consider ordering a supernatural object detector from one of your favorite science suppliers, as the pilot wave is a supernatural object that can not be detected with ordinary lab equipment. Make sure the product you chose got a four star or better rating from previous buyers.

Comment: Good joke, but the quantum phase of the Aharonov-Bohm effect seems to be measurable and real.

Comment: And it isn't supernatural, either. It readily drops out of ordinary quantum mechanics. Technically speaking an ordinary transformer demonstrates a very similar effect (induction in a coil that is located in a region that is mostly free of a magnetic field) using nothing but classical field theory and high school physics.

Comment: I didn’t know that you consider pilot wave theory to be supernatural. 
I’m interested in the interaction of photons with phonons.

Comment: Phonons are quantized lattice vibrations of solids. Are your flutes made from solid transparent crystals? That's quite unusual, I would say.

Comment: Im trying to extend the concept of crystals to gas trapped in the tube. THis gas originally would be at room temperature and atmospheric pressure. The energy of the gas follows the Boltzmann distribution.  However, at the time when a sustained sound wave has been created the energies of the molecules are far from equilibrium. The random movement of molecules is replaced by the normal modes each mode being part of the harmonic series . Anormal mode is a pattern  in which all parts

Comment: I'm trying to extend the concept of crystals to gas trapped in the tube. This gas originally would be at room temperature and atmospheric pressure. The energy of the gas follows the Boltzmann distribution.  However, at the time when a sustained sound wave has been created the energies of the molecules are far from equilibrium. The random movement of molecules is replaced by the normal modes each mode being part of the harmonic series. A normal mode is a pattern in which all parts of the system move sinusoidally with the same frequency and with a fixed phase relation behaving like a crystal.

Comment: IN solid crystalline structure is fixed but in the flute as above can be varied creating instantanouse  crystalline-like structures

Comment: Standing pressure waves could be interpreted as the oscillations of the scalar field, and quantized oscillations represent phonons.